# Redirección de rutas con Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirección, rutas

Tengo un método en un controlador así:

```
public function metodo1(Request $request)
{
    dump($request);
}
```

Este método se llama con un enrutamiento con nombre. En `web.php` lo tengo así:

```
Route::post('pagina1', 'Controlador@metodo1')
    ->name('primero');
```

Hasta aquí, todo funciona bien. Ahora, desde otro método, quiero redireccionar al anterior. Lo he puesto así:

```
public function metodo2(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()
        ->route('primero')
        ->withInput([
            'id' => $request->id
        ]);
}
```

El objetivo es que los datos que hay en el método `withInput()` pasen por post al primer método, y entres en él por la variable `$request`. Sin embargo, me da un error en la consola del navegador, así:

```
GET http://pruebas.lar/metodo1 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Es como si la redirección no pudiera hacerse por **post**, sino que estuviera intentando hacerla por **get** a la fuerza.

El caso es que desde `metodo2` necesito pasar datos a `metodo1`, y necesito que pasen por **post**, para entrar en `$request`, que es como `metodo1` los espera.

En la docu no he encontrado detalles de esto. Solo aparece la sintaxis básica. Podéis ayudarme? Necesito que se redireccione por **post** y pase los datos en la petición. Hay algún método específico para esto?

Comment: Y que ruta le pusiste al metodo2??.....como accedes a el????

Answer (score 1):

Este es un problema típico que he visto muchas veces en StackOverflow y en la vida diaria.

Para responder a la pregunta: **NO es posible hacer un redirección POST en Laravel**.

Esto es considerado un error de diseño, y deberías tener un servicio u otra capa que permita acceder a lo que intentes hacer en la ruta POST desde los dos métodos o controladores (el de la ruta POST y el que intenta redirigir).

Entonces, en vez de intentar una redirección, crea otra capa que te permita acceder de forma segura a procesar dicha información, puedes inyectarlo en el método si así lo deseas:

```
public function metodo2(Request $request, MyService $myService)
{
    $myService->processData($request->id);
}
```

Comment: Aquí ando un poco perdida. el método processData() es nativo de algún servicio específico? Como podría poner un sevicio que recibiera los datos e hiciera la llamada por post pasándolos a metodo1? Por lo que he leido, el servicio ese iría dentro de AppServiceProvider, pero no sé muy bien como crear ese servicio. Si pudieras darme algunos detalles, al menos para empezar, para que el servicio lance peticiones HTTP por post, te lo agradecería.

Comment: El servicio no tiene nada que ver con una solicitud HTTP, es simplemente otra capa de tu aplicación. Tómalo casi como un patrón de diseño. Las solicitudes HTTP están en otro nivel, más externo.

Comment: Ahora si que me he perdido. Se supone que el servicio debe recibir los datos de metodo2 e inyectárselos a metodo1. Al menos es lo que intento poder hacer. Me temo que no te he entendido.

Comment: En unas horas te podré dar una explicación más detallada, en estos momentos no puedo. Puedes revisar el papel de un servicio en diseño de software.

Comment: Además, que tendría que tener ese servicio para poder pasar los datos a metodo1? De verdad que no lo tengo nada claro. Llevo horas en Internet y haciendo pruebas, y cada vez tengo el código más liado y no me funciona. Por favor, pon un ejemplo concreto, con una sintaxis que pueda buscar en Internet para entenderlo.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con Shaz.

Podrías realizar lo que querés de multiples maneras sin hacer redirecciones de ese tipo.
En este momento se me ocurren dos opciones alternativas a la que te planteó Shaz.

1) Disparar un [Evento](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events). `event(new OrderShipped($order));`

```
public function metodo2(Request $request)
{
    // Se ejecuta el codigo que quieras y luego se dispara un evento
    event(new MetodoEvent($request->id));
    return view...
}
```

2) Podés llamar a el metodo1 desde el mismo controlador.

```
public function metodo2(Request $request)
{
    // Se ejecuta el codigo que quieras y luego se dispara un evento
    $metodo1 = $this->metodo1($request->id);
    return view(...)->with('result',$metodo1);
}
```

Existen muchas otras formas, quizá podrías hacer una lista de las alternativas que se te ocurran y evaluarlas, todo depende de que es exactamente lo que desees hacer. Acá planteaste métodos genéricos sin especificar que tarea deben realizar pero si estas trabajando con Modelos podrías incluso agregar un método al modelo, si es una tarea relacionada a un modelo que también querés tenerla disponible en otros modelos quizá podrías crear un trait o incluso si es una funcionalidad que querés realizar desde cualquier lugar podrías pensar en un helper o un servicio. Todo depende de como estes enfocando el diseño de tu aplicación.

Por otra parte si lo único que necesitás hacer es agregar datos al request podes hacer algo como:

```
$request->request->add(['id' => $request->id]);
```

**O mas simple aun**

```
$inputs = $request->all();
$inputs['id'] = $request->id;
```

Espero mi aporte sea util.
Saludos

Comment: Me temo que no he explicado bien en mi problema. Intentaré ser más clara. Tengo un método que recibe una petición de tipo Request, al que se accede por post. Dentro de ese método se procesan algunos datos, se crean otros, y el conjunto de datos resultante necesito enviarlo a otro método, para que llegue también como una Request. Además, con los datos que se envían tiene que ir, también, el token csrf, para evitar errores.

Vamos que, en un método se genera un paquete de datos, que no sé si debe generarse con response, y debo poder enviarlo a otro método con nombre (usando route(), creo).

Comment: Como dijo Shaz es un problema de diseño.
si ya ingresaste al sistema no necesitas generar otro request ni tampoco necesitas el token y menos una redireccion.
Un metodo puede retornar cualquier cosa no solo instancias de `Response`. Como podés ver en la opcion 2 el `metodo1` retorna un array (o lo que sea) que es capturado en una variable llamada `$metodo1` y luego esa data es compartida con la vista. Me parece que **s**i estas explicando lo que queres hacer pero el tema es q lo q queres hacer quizá no es lo q se debería hacer.